# Ruby stop Telnet echo the command sent

Tags: ruby, telnet

I like to know if there is an option to suppress the command I run on the remote machine via Ruby Telnet library.  Here is code:

```
server = Net::Telnet::new("Host" => $hosts,
                          "Timeout" => 10,
                          "Prompt" => /[$%#>]/n)
server.login($user, $pass)
server.cmd("ls -1 /tmp/myfile.txt") do |c|
    puts c
end
```

the out put will be:

```
ls -1 /tmp/myfile.txt
/tmp/myfile.txt
$
```

where $ is the prompt.  I would like to see only the "/tmp/myfile.txt" returned.  So I do not have to filter the returns in my script to ignore the original command and the prompt.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it always outputs a shell prompt at the end, what about stripping the last line of output? I don't believe there's anything special inside of NET::Telnet to prevent this. You could also try using [PTY with expect](http://www.42klines.com/2010/08/14/what-to-expect-from-the-ruby-expect-library.html) method to handle telnet instead.

Comment: I think I could get away by stripping prompt at the last line of output .  However, I don't understand why the command itself got echoed back..  I hope there is some option in the Ruby Telnet library that would turn-off echo .

Comment: Well with PTY+Expect you can set verbose to false. Check out: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/83119